# Copy a pointer (is a function parameter) to another one (a global var) in C++

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

On this project I use some `Objective-C++` code mixed with `C++` code.

I know this is basic, but I don't know how to copy a pointer passed as a parameter on a method to a pointer in the class.

I show you my code:

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
    ...

    int* _lastDetectionClasses;
}

@end

@implementation MyClass

...

- (int)doSomething:(uint8_t *)aPointer
    detection:(int*)detectionClasses
{
    [ ... ]

    _lastDetectionClasses = detectionClasses;

    return -1;
}

    [ ... ]
}
```

**Is this line `_lastDetectionClasses = detectionClasses;` correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want.

If you **really** want what you described in the title and what you wrote, then it's correct - you're copying a pointer to an instance variable declared as the same type of pointer.

If you, however, want to copy the contents of the memory pointed to by the pointer, then you will need to allocate some memory and use `memcpy()`.